# exception not caught / exception handling not working

Tags: java, exception

I have the following code with excpetion handling, which does not work:

**`LoadQuestionsDataButton::actionPerformed(ActionEvent)`:**

```
try
{
    questions = ParseXml.parseQuestionsData(questionsDataFile);

    // only for broken xml-files!
} catch (java.lang.Exception e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainWindow, "<html><body>The XML-file seems to be corrupt:<br><br>" +
            e.getMessage() +
            ".</body></html>", "Corrupt XML-file.", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

    System.out.println("error-message");

    return;
} catch (AssertionError e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainWindow, "<html>The XML-file seems to be corrupt.<br></html>", "Fehler beim Laden der XML-Datei.", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

    return;
}
```

**`ArrayList<Question> ParseXml::parseQuestionsData(File)`:**

```
if(number == "")
{
    Exception e;
    System.out.println("before exception");

    if(firstQuestion)
        e = new Exception("The first question does not contain numbering!");
    else
        e = new Exception("The Question after <" + lastNumber + "> does not contain numbering!");

    System.out.println("after exception creation");

    throw e;
}
```

When I load a XML-file with `number == ""`, then "before exception" and "after exception creation" get printed, but the error-message-dialog and "error-message" does not!

It also displays the stack trace:

```
before exception
after exception creation
java.lang.Exception: The first question does not contain numbering!
    at com.examquestions.Buttons.ParseXml.parseQuestionsData(ParseXml.java:60)
    at com.examquestions.Buttons.LoadQuestionsDataButton.actionPerformed(LoadQuestionsDataButton.java:65)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
[...]
```

[stacktrace on pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/PDmPW092)

I can't show more of the stacktrace here, because stackoverflow complains about having too much code.

Comment: Could you add the whole `parseQuestionsData` method ?

Comment: @Berger that was it! you are right: I had the wohle `parseQuestionsData(File)` surrounded in try-catch with `e.printStackTrace()` in the `catch`-Block! Didn't remember that. Thank you.

Comment: Is your `if` block in a `try` block?

Answer (score 0):

I had the wohle `parseQuestionsData(File)` surrounded in `try-catch` with `e.printStackTrace()` in the `catch`-Block.

This could not work. Didn't remember that.